# hcitool lescan input/output error on Ubuntu 18.04 with Intel AX200NGW

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth, ubuntu-18.04, bluez

My goal is to have `hcitool lescan` running on Ubuntu 18.04 with a BLE 5.0 radio.

I upgraded the internal WiFi/Bluetooth card in a Dell Precision 7520 laptop from the original Qualcomm QCA61x4A (BLE 4.2) to Intel AX200NGW (BLE 5.0). Before the swap, no issues with `hcitool lescan`. After the hardware swap, 

 `# hcitool lescan
Set scan parameters failed: Input/output error
 # hciconfig hci0 down && hciconfig hci0 up && hcitool lescan
Set scan parameters failed: Input/output error
 # hciconfig hci0 down && hciconfig hci0 up && service bluetooth restart && hcitool lescan
Could not open device: No such device
 # hciconfig hci0 down && hciconfig hci0 up && service bluetooth restart && sleep 1 && hcitool lescan
Set scan parameters failed: Input/output error
 # service bluetooth stop && hciconfig hci0 down && hciconfig hci0 up && hcitool lescan
Set scan parameters failed: Input/output error`

Both before and after the hardware swap, both bluetoothctl and GUI interface work just fine. 

 `# bluetoothctl
[bluetooth]# menu scan
[bluetooth]# clear
SetDiscoveryFilter success
[bluetooth]# back
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started`

[Ubuntu GUI Settings - Bluetooth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjl2N.png)

Some basic System Information after installing new Intel AX200NGW

 `# hciconfig -a
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
        BD Address: 5C:80:B6:58:52:D6  ACL MTU: 1021:4  SCO MTU: 96:6
        UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN INQUIRY
        RX bytes:284131 acl:758 sco:6 events:4443 errors:0
        TX bytes:747220 acl:72 sco:1 commands:3530 errors:0
        Features: 0xbf 0xfe 0x0f 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
        Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3
        Link policy: RSWITCH SNIFF
        Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT
        Name: 'Ubuntu-1804-Laptop'
        Class: 0x1c010c
        Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing, Object Transfer
        Device Class: Computer, Laptop
        HCI Version: 5.0 (0x9)  Revision: 0x100
        LMP Version: 5.0 (0x9)  Subversion: 0x100
        Manufacturer: Intel Corp. (2)
 # uname -a
Linux Ubuntu-1804-Laptop 5.3.0-26-generic #28~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 18 16:40:14 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
 # bluetoothd -v
5.48`

Comment: Hello there. Did you try updating bluez to version 5.52?

Comment: I just tried Bluez 5.52 on both Ubuntu 18.04 and 19.10. Same results. Tried different hardware (Dell Precision 7520, Dell Edge Gateway 5000, OnLogic Karbon 300). Everyone time I install an BLE 5.0 radio, hcitool lescan fails. Swap radios to a 4.0 or 4.2, and hcitool lescan works.

Comment: The BLE 5.0 radio...is it the same Intel adapter each time? Are you sure you don't have a defective adapter?

Comment: I sourced four BLE 5.0 radios (https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07SH6GV5S) (https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07YN27322) (https://www.newegg.com/fenvi-fv-ax200hmw-mini-pci-express/p/0XM-00JK-00079) (https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/wireless/wireless-products/dual-band-wireless-ac-9260.html)

Comment: @AlexVallo did you find anything? I'm running into the same issue

Comment: @cjds https://stackoverflow.com/a/60322966/7459984